# How can I find the largest increase in value of the elements of this list and then return the corresponding year and actual value it increased by

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
MIDYEAR_POPULATION = [(1971, 21962032), (1972, 22218463), (1973, 22491777), (1974, 22807969), (1975, 23143275), 
                  (1976, 23449808), (1977, 23725843), (1978, 23963203), (1979, 24201544), (1980, 24515667),
                  (1981, 24819915), (1982, 25116942), (1983, 25366451), (1984, 25607053), (1985, 25842116),
                  (1986, 26100278), (1987, 26446601), (1988, 26791747), (1989, 27276781), (1990, 27691138),
                  (1991, 28037420), (1992, 28371264), (1993, 28684764), (1994, 29000663), (1995, 29302311),
                  (1996, 29610218), (1997, 29905948), (1998, 30155173), (1999, 30401286), (2000, 30685730),
                  (2001, 31020596), (2002, 31358418), (2003, 31641630), (2004, 31938004), (2005, 32242364),
                  (2006, 32570505), (2007, 32887928), (2008, 33245773), (2009, 33628571), (2010, 34005274), 
                  (2011, 34342780), (2012, 34750545), (2013, 35152370), (2014, 35535348), (2015, 35832513), 
                  (2016, 36264604), (2017, 36708083), (2018, 37057765), (2019, 37589262)]

def greatest_increase(pop_stats):
    max_increase = MIDYEAR_POPULATION[1][1] - MIDYEAR_POPULATION[0][1]
    for (year, population) in MIDYEAR_POPULATION[::-1]:

    # so here I would want to find which value of population in the lists increases the most from year to year, and then return the year and how much it increased by.

def main():
    greatest_increase(pop_stats)

main()
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
>>> max_diff = 0
>>> max_elem = -1
>>> for a,b in zip(MIDYEAR_POPULATION, MIDYEAR_POPULATION[1:]) :
...     diff = abs(a[1]-b[1])
...     if diff > max_diff :
...         max_diff = diff
...         max_elem = b  # or a
... 
>>> print max_diff, max_elem
531497 (2019, 37589262)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other users here have already contributed great responses, but I would like to suggest an alternative solution using [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html). [Link to numpy.diff documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

```
def get_largest_increase():                                                         
    global MIDYEAR_POPULATION                                                              
    # reformat data                                                                        
    years, populations = zip(*MIDYEAR_POPULATION)                                          
    populations = numpy.array(populations)                                                 

    # get index of max diff, note that +1 is required b/c diff returns len(arr)-1          
    diffs = numpy.diff(populations)
    largest_increase_idx = numpy.argmax(diffs)                      
    return (years[largest_increase_idx+1],int(diffs[largest_increase_idx]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another problem which can use a recursion:

```
def local_max_increase(a, b):
    """ Compare 2 tuples and return the
    max according to their second element
    """
    return max(a, b, key=lambda x: x[1])

def get_max_increase(population, current_max =None):
    """ Compute the increase in population between 2
    consecutive years and return the year with the highest increase.
    """
    candidate= (population[1][0], population[1][1]-population[0][1])
    if current_max :
        candidate= local_max_increase(current_max, candidate)
    if len(population) == 2:
        return candidate
    return get_max_increase(population[1:], candidate)

print('Year with max increase:', get_max_increase(MIDYEAR_POPULATION))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pop_df = pd.DataFrame(MIDYEAR_POPULATION, columns=['year', 'population'])
pop_df['pop_increase'] = pop_df['population'] - pop_df['population'].shift()

import numpy as np
print(np.max(pop_df['pop_increase']))
print(pop_df['year'][np.argmax(pop_df['pop_increase'])])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `key` parameter in the `max()` and `min()` functions:

```
def greatest_increase():
    maxPop = max(MIDYEAR_POPULATION, key=lambda x: x[1])
    minPop = min(MIDYEAR_POPULATION, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return minPop, maxPop
```

(This returns the least and most population years. You can edit this to find the increase, etc.)

Comment: your post does not answer ANY of the questions asked.